# how to create fad-in and fad-out video?

Tags: android, video, android-ffmpeg, github-hub

This command used to create fad in and fad out from :

https://androidlearnersite.wordpress.com/2017/03/17/ffmpeg-video-editor/comment-page-1/#comment-150

```
 String[] command = {"-y", "-i", file.getAbsolutePath(), "-acodec", "copy", 
 "-vf", "fade=t=in:st=0:d=5,fade=t=out:st=" + 
 String.valueOf((Share.size_of_images * 3sec) - 5) + ":d=5", 
 file1.getAbsolutePath()};

 video path = file.getAbsolutePath() 
 output path = file2.getAbsolutepath()
```

Tired to create this.
please help me.